# Why does \ifthenelse not work?

Tags: pgfmath, ifthenelse

Im currently dealing with a problem in my code. I keep getting the error `use of \nextx does not match its definition` From the `\pgfmathsetmacro\nextAsInt...` line. But i cant see the problem. It should return an Integer.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{-15}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = 1]

        \def \xy{{  {2, 1, 0.5, 1}, 
                    {4, 1, 2, 3}, 
                    {3, 2, 4, 1}, 
                    {0.5, 3, 5, 4}}}

        \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
            \foreach \y in {0,...,3}{
                \pgfmathsetmacro\asInt{int(\xy[\y][\x])}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\r{(\asInt+1)/2}
                
                \def \nextx \ifthenelse {\x=3} {\value{\x}} {\value{\x+1}}
                \def \nexty \ifthenelse {\y=3} {\value{\y}} {\value{\y+1}}

                \pgfmathsetmacro\nextAsInt{int(\xy[int(\nextx)][int(\nexty)])}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\nextr{(\nextAsInt+1)/2}

                \draw[thick, blue, -](\x+0.5,\y+0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\r);
                \draw[fill = blue](\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\r) circle (2pt);
                \draw[thick, green, -](\x,\y+0.5,\r) -- (\nextx,\nexty,\nextr)
            }
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advantage.

Comment: of course, • you forgot the braces, and • ifthenelse is not expandable. "things not explicitly allowed is prohibited"

Comment: `\def \nextx \ifthenelse {\x=3} ` defines `\nextx` such that if it is not followed by `\ifthenelse` you get a parse error, and `\nextx \ifthenelse` will expand to `\x=3` . The token `\ifthenelse` is never executed in this context (it does not even need to be defined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't work for several reasons. The first is that `\def` works in a different way than you seem to believe; the second one is that `\value` is a specific command for *counters*, not to retrieve the value of some arithmetic expression.

You are better served with `\pgfmathsetmacro` instead:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\nextx{\x==3 ? \x : \x+1}
```

This is common syntax also in other programming languages: the condition before `?` either returns 1 (if the test is true) or 0 (if the test is false); when 1 the branch before the colon is taken, otherwise the one after the colon.

I'm not sure whether the output is what you were looking for, but if I add some debugging information after having set the variables, I get

```
*** \x=0; \nextx=1.0; \y=0; \nexty=1.0 ***
*** \x=0; \nextx=1.0; \y=1; \nexty=2.0 ***
*** \x=0; \nextx=1.0; \y=2; \nexty=3.0 ***
*** \x=0; \nextx=1.0; \y=3; \nexty=3 ***
*** \x=1; \nextx=2.0; \y=0; \nexty=1.0 ***
*** \x=1; \nextx=2.0; \y=1; \nexty=2.0 ***
*** \x=1; \nextx=2.0; \y=2; \nexty=3.0 ***
*** \x=1; \nextx=2.0; \y=3; \nexty=3 ***
*** \x=2; \nextx=3.0; \y=0; \nexty=1.0 ***
*** \x=2; \nextx=3.0; \y=1; \nexty=2.0 ***
*** \x=2; \nextx=3.0; \y=2; \nexty=3.0 ***
*** \x=2; \nextx=3.0; \y=3; \nexty=3 ***
*** \x=3; \nextx=3; \y=0; \nexty=1.0 ***
*** \x=3; \nextx=3; \y=1; \nexty=2.0 ***
*** \x=3; \nextx=3; \y=2; \nexty=3.0 ***
*** \x=3; \nextx=3; \y=3; \nexty=3 ***
```

so you can see the cycles at work. Change the `\iffalse` into `\iftrue` if you want to see the same (but then remove the whole block when you're certain about the correct values).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{-15}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = 1]

  \def \xy{{%
    {2, 1, 0.5, 1}, 
    {4, 1, 2, 3}, 
    {3, 2, 4, 1}, 
    {0.5, 3, 5, 4}%
  }}

  \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,3}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro\asInt{int(\xy[\y][\x])}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\r{(\asInt+1)/2}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\nextx{\x==3 ? \x : \x+1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\nexty{\y==3 ? \y : \y+1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\nextAsInt{int(\xy[int(\nextx)][int(\nexty)])}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\nextr{(\nextAsInt+1)/2}

      \iffalse
        \message{***
          \string\x=\x; \string\nextx=\nextx;
          \string\y=\y; \string\nexty=\nexty
          \space***^^J%
        }
      \fi

      \draw[thick, blue, -](\x+0.5,\y+0.5,0) -- (\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\r);
      \draw[fill = blue](\x+0.5,\y+0.5,\r) circle (2pt);
      \draw[thick, green, -](\x,\y+0.5,\r) -- (\nextx,\nexty,\nextr);
    }
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. With some finetuning (I missed some coordinates) i managed to get a nice image.